# Mariadb mysql-slow-query.log

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, mariadb, centos6.5

Can some one advise me about this:

OS: CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

MYsql:  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.38-MariaDB

9.1G    /srv/mysql/mysql-slow-query.log

1.1G    /srv/mysql/ib_logfile0

1.1G    /srv/mysql/ib_logfile1

I have Maria db which has mysql-slow-query.log and it is 9.1G, So I don't have so mach space on my server to give for log. Can someone advise me what can i Do wit this, can I delete some lines in it or can i totally remove this log.
Free space: 13G  17%

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Execute `FLUSH SLOW LOGS;`.  I suspect that will not suffice.  So...

`mv` the slow log to change its name, *then* do `FLUSH SLOW LOGS;`.  Now you will have 2 files, the 9GB one and a freshly started one.  `rm` the old one when you through with it.

I might suggest you grab the output of `pt-query-digest` before doing any of the above.  After all, that's why you turned the slowlog on, correct?

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/flush/